# ML.Net как получить predictionLable строкой

Tags: c#, .net, машинное-обучение

UPD: Решено.

Происходит ошибка на моменте создания предиктора, что не подходят типы, он ожидает Key, но получает string, если я меняю в классе DataPrediction тип на UInt32, то все работает но в качестве ответа получаю код, вопрос такой, можно ли как-то указать во время преобразования что входной тип строка или как-то преобразовать код в строку после получения результата

```
IDataView data = loader.Load(source);

var pipeline = 
    context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(outputColumnName: "Features", inputColumnName: "Features")
    .Append(context.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label","Label"),TransformerScope.TrainTest)
    .Append(context.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy())
    .Append(context.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("PredictedData", "PredictedLabel"));

var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
var predictor = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<DataRw, DataPrediction>(model);

var rw = new DataRw()
{ Data = "Данные" };

var prediction = predictor.Predict(rw);
```

```
public class DataRw
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    [ColumnName("Features")]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class DataPrediction
{
    public string PredictedData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 3 Append заменить MapValueToKey, на MapKeyToValue